# How to Clear Office Clipboard with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

How would you clear the Microsoft Office Clipboard using VBA, specifically Word VBA?

I am copying a lot of data at time into the clipboard and don't want excessive data kept in the Clipboard.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38742157) is a one-liner using the Windows Script Host. Don't forget to upvote it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Saw this on another post, and I have tested it with Word VBA.

```
'Clearing the Office Clipboard

    Dim oData   As New DataObject 'object to use the clipboard

    oData.SetText text:=Empty 'Clear
    oData.PutInClipboard 'take in the clipboard to empty it
```

Just copy and paste into your code where ever you need to clear the Clipboard.

Another thing I noticed is that when I `.Quit` a program, say Excel, it keeps asking me if I want to keep the data is the Clipboard. A work around is to clear the clipboard using the above stated code. See below:

```
'Clearing the Office Clipboard

    Dim oData   As New DataObject 'object to use the clipboard

    oData.SetText text:=Empty 'Clear
    oData.PutInClipboard 'take in the clipboard to empty it


'You can also just remove the Alert Messages from the Excel Program while    
'the code is running
'Remove alert Messages from the Excel Program when closing
ExcelProgram.DisplayAlerts = False   

'Quiting the Excel Application
ExcelProgram.Quit
```

I used the above example in a VBA code to import data from an Excel File. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32738849/copying-data-from-an-excel-file-in-word-using-word-vba)

Comment: I get an error 'user defined type not defined'

Answer (score 19):

Would a simple

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

work for your situation, or is this option not viable?

Comment: Thanks I have seen that before, but never tried it. It does works for my application as well. It basically removes the CutCopy function which will automatically remove the clipboard data.

Comment: I like this solution since it doesn't require adding a reference to an object library.

Comment: Worth noting that this only clears the Excel clipboard. If you have anything else in your clipboard this has no effect. Fine for the question, but Google serves me this question when I'm looking for a way to clear the clipboard in a macro, for which I need to truly clear the clipboard - and this top-voted answer for MY question doesn't actually help me.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution that worked for me.  This is based on a post by by Zack Barresse on [VBAexpress.com](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=205):

```
Public Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Public Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long

Public Sub ClearClipboard()
    OpenClipboard (0&)
    EmptyClipboard
    CloseClipboard
End Sub
```

After copying this function to your VBA project, use `ClearClipboard` to clear it.

Comment: Years later, but if anyone is hunting for how to do this in Office 365 under 64-Bit, you now need to use the modifications for backwards compatibility to make this work:

Private Declare PtrSafe  and LongPtr as your two changes to these values will resolve issues and allow it to still work.

Answer (score 2):

A quick and easy solution I've just used is

```
MyDoc.Range.Characters(1).Copy
```

Where "MyDoc" is the name of the document you are using.

It doesn't technically *empty* the clipboard, it just makes it one character long (assuming your document starts with characters), which stops Word from popping up with annoying questions.

The purists may not like it, but heyho, it's dead easy :)

Answer (score 2):

If any one is like me and just grabs code and bashes it with the programing hammer until it fits your needs: The above solution updated for a modern era with the `ptrsafe` and `longptr` already added. In case, much like myself, you have no idea what they mean and it would take far too long to figure out where to put them.

```vb
Option Explicit
Public Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As LongPtr
Public Declare PtrSafe Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As LongPtr
Public Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As LongPtr

Public Function ClearClipboard()
    OpenClipboard (0&)
    EmptyClipboard
    CloseClipboard
End Function

Sub ccc()
    Call ClearClipboard
End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent! I like the x64 Bit ready code! thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is held within the library "Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library".  To link to that library go to the VBA editor, then Tools, References and pick it out from the list if it's not already ticked.

You can do more funky stuff with a bunch of WinAPI calls, but I generally prefer avoiding those unless absolutely necessary.

Also, don't forget about the DisplayAlerts property, which will suppress dialog boxes - although I'm not sure if it would always produce the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for that, the `DisplayAlerts` property worked great for blocking the Alert from Excel. I think for use of importing data from Excel repeatedly, it will be beneficial to clear the Clipboard at the end of each `Loop`

Comment: Just to confirm; that property is available within Word as well.  I've not checked how Word's enumeration values compare with Excel's for that property.

Comment: I used the `DisplayAlerts` in Word and Excel and the debugger was happy, so I believe it will be fine. In Word will use `Application.DisplayAlerts` and for the Active Excel Program which was Opened it is the same as what is displayed above

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting the error while closing the workbook, Use code something like this

```
wbk.close False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```