# Excel Clipboard Clear

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a newbie on writing excel macros but I'm struggling to get things done. Anyway, I'm trying to export data from 2 worksheets to another 2 worksheets in another workbook, but when I reach the point of clearing the clipboard, it simply doesn't work :( could anyone help me please ? Here's my code:

```
Sub manufacturer_export()

Dim Return_Shipment_Template_Proba As Workbook
Dim wbTarget As Workbook
Dim activeSht As Worksheet

    Set Return_Shipment_Template_Proba = ThisWorkbook
    Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open("file:///F:\FEM Backup\20.07.2016\08_GT Returns & Sample tracking\01_Returns Summary\Returns Summary.xlsm")

Set activeSht = Return_Shipment_Template_Proba.Sheets("GT_GU10_Lamp")
    With Return_Shipment_Template_Proba.Sheets("GT_GU10_Lamp").Range("A3:X3")
' Column B may be empty. If so, xlDown will return cell C65536
' and whole empty column will be copied... prevent this.
        If .Cells(1, 24).Value = "" Then
    'Nothing in this column.
    'Do nothing.
    Else
    Return_Shipment_Template_Proba.Sheets("GT_GU10_Lamp").Range(.Cells(1, 24), .End(xlDown)).Copy
    wbTarget.Sheets("GT_GU10_Lamp").Activate
    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=True, Transpose:=False
End If
End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Set activeSht = Return_Shipment_Template_Proba.Sheets("GT_COB_GU10_Lamp")
With       Return_Shipment_Template_Proba.Sheets("GT_COB_GU10_Lamp").Range("A3:X3")
' Column B may be empty. If so, xlDown will return cell C65536
' and whole empty column will be copied... prevent this.
    If .Cells(1, 24).Value = "" Then
    'Nothing in this column.
    'Do nothing.
        Else
    Return_Shipment_Template_Proba.Sheets("GT_COB_GU10_Lamp").Range(.Cells(1, 24), .End(xlDown)).Copy
    wbTarget.Sheets("GT_COB_GU10_Lamp").Activate
    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=True, Transpose:=False
End If

End With

wbTarget.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: What do exactly do you mean by "simply doesn't work"? Is there an error somewhere?  I'm also not exactly sure what you mean by "clearing the clipboard". Are you referring to `Return_Shipment_Template.Application.CutCopyMode = False`?

Comment: Instead of `Return_Shipment_Template.Application.CutCopyMode = False` try `Application.CutCopyMode = False`

Comment: When I say it doesn't work, I mean It copies the same data from the first source sheet to both destination sheets.

Comment: Have you tried using a Worksheet variable, such as `Dim activeSht As Worksheet Set activeSht = Return_Shipment_Template.Sheets("GT_GU10_Lamp") With activeSht.Range("A3:X3") ... End With` and repeating for the second sheet

Comment: `Range(.Cells(1, 24), .End(xlDown)).Copy` , this line is troublesome : the firs range is not referenced by a point "." and the cells are... so it will copy from the active worksheet of course.

Comment: instead of `activate / copy / Paste` you can also do like this : `WB_A.SheetA.Range("WhateverA").copy WB_B.SheetB.Range("WhateverB")` , in one line

Comment: Hello Michael, I followed your advice and I used a Worksheet variable but I'm having the same problem. The copy selection remains on the first source sheet. This is the updated code :

Comment: I can't paste the code here 'cause it's too long.

Comment: Patrick, the way you suggest me is for a defined range. But my Source workbook is a template that can have variable amount of rows for each shipment that I receive. Basically I have to track some faulty products that return to the seller.

Comment: Het guys I finally made it :) it seems it wasn't enough to activate the sheet before the 'With' module. I also had to add complete reference to the range(see the code). Anyway, thank you very much guys !!!!!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using API calls, you can use this to clear the windows clipboard:

```
Private Sub ClearClipboard()
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "CMD /C @ECHO OFF | CLIP", 0, False
End Sub

'// Example

Sub Foo()

'// Do something here...
ClearClipboard
'// clipboard is now empty

End Sub
```

Comment: Doesnt seem to clear the clipboard. I can still see things piled up in the Clipboard view even after running this command

Answer (score -1):

this is a 64 bit code for clearing the clipboard, using API's:

Frankly your error is not in the clipboard (see my comments), but here goes :

```
Option Explicit

'Open the clipboard to read
Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As Long

'clear clipboard
Public Declare PtrSafe Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long

'Close the clipboard
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long




Sub Clear_Clipboard()
OpenClipboard (0&)
EmptyClipboard
CloseClipboard
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```