# Clearing the clipboard in Office 365

Tags: vba, ms-word, office365, clipboard

I am using Office 365 under Windows 10, 64 bit. I am trying to clear the clipboard. The macro recorder produces an empty sub.

The following attempts are mostly collected from [How to Clear Office Clipboard with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32736915/how-to-clear-office-clipboard-with-vba) :

```vb
Option Explicit
Public Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Public Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long

Public Sub ClearClipboardA()
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

Public Sub ClearClipBoardB()
    ' Source: http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=462
    Dim oData As New DataObject
    oData.SetText Text:=Empty ' Clear
    oData.PutInClipboard ' Putting empty text into the clipboard to empty it
End Sub

Public Sub ClearClipboardC()
    OpenClipboard (0&)
    EmptyClipboard
    CloseClipboard
End Sub
```

Version A:

> Method or data member not found

Version B: Runs without clearing the clipboard.  A small yellow status window appears shortly:

> "7 of 24 - Clipboard | Element not fetched"

(translated into English)

Version C: Nothing seems to happen.

In the above reference user iamstrained writes: “... if anyone is hunting for how to do this in Office 365 under 64-Bit, you now need to use the modifications for backwards compatibility to make this work: `Private Declare PtrSafe` and `LongPtr` as your two changes to these values will resolve issues and allow it to still work.”

I found a reference to a Microsoft page, where this has perhaps been done:

https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/office/vba/access/Concepts/Windows-API/send-information-to-the-clipboard

Using subs shown here I can insert text into the clipboard and extract from it, but not clear it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Clear Office Clipboard with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32736915/how-to-clear-office-clipboard-with-vba)

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38742157) is a one-liner using the Windows Script Host that you can add to the collection. Or not?

Answer (score 3):

to clear the office Clipboard (from Excel):

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function AccessibleChildren Lib "oleacc" (ByVal paccContainer As Office.IAccessible, _
    ByVal iChildStart As Long, ByVal cChildren As Long, _
    ByRef rgvarChildren As Any, ByRef pcObtained As Long) As Long
    Public Const myVBA7 As Long = 1
#Else
    Private Declare Function AccessibleChildren Lib "oleacc" (ByVal paccContainer As Office.IAccessible, _
                                                              ByVal iChildStart As Long, ByVal cChildren As Long, _
                                                              ByRef rgvarChildren As Any, ByRef pcObtained As Long) As Long
    Public Const myVBA7 As Long = 0
#End If

Public Sub EvRClearOfficeClipBoard()
    Dim cmnB, IsVis As Boolean, j As Long, Arr As Variant
    Arr = Array(4, 7, 2, 0)                      '4 and 2 for 32 bit, 7 and 0 for 64 bit
    Set cmnB = Application.CommandBars("Office Clipboard")
    IsVis = cmnB.Visible
    If Not IsVis Then
        cmnB.Visible = True
        DoEvents
    End If

    For j = 1 To Arr(0 + myVBA7)
        AccessibleChildren cmnB, Choose(j, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 1), 1, cmnB, 1
    Next
        
    cmnB.accDoDefaultAction CLng(Arr(2 + myVBA7))

    Application.CommandBars("Office Clipboard").Visible = IsVis

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have tested your macro in both Excel and Word and it does indeed clear the clipboards! I am puzzled by the addition "0 + myVBA7" in the for-loop. The function Choose was unknown to me, it seems quite useful.

Comment: For the win32 version you need: 0,3,0,3 (so 4 steps) and do defaultaction 2& (1& for PasteAll) For the win64 version you need: 0,3,0,3,0,3,1 (so 7 steps) and do the defaultaction 0& (For PasteAll 0,3,0,3,0,3,0) This was the shortest way to write this Sub which will work for both versions

Comment: This is the only version of this that has worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the code below clears the Windows clipboard

```
#If Win64 Then
Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As Long
Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Declare PtrSafe Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
#Else
Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Declare Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
#End If

Public Sub ClearClipboard()
   OpenClipboard (0&)
   EmptyClipboard
   CloseClipboard
End Sub
```

You can download the pointer safe declarations from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=9970

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I downloaded Office2010Win32API_PtrSafe.exe from the link you provided, executed it as administrator,
copied the code you provided to a new module and ran it.
Unfortunately it had no effect on the content of the clipboard.

Comment: @HolgerNielsen - are you sure that you had something in the clipboard to begin with? I copied a block of text from your question pasted it into a new text document then ran that code. Clipboard was empty. I am using O365 on Win 10 x64.

Comment: Yes, I have Word's clipboard open, so I can see if something is added or deleted. I have searched my C: drive for "user32", there are several user32.dll there, but none with a recent time stamp, if that is significant. Is there anyway I can check, that the installation of the PtrSave elements has been done? Should I try to run the installation .exe file once more? Thank you for your supporting remarks!

Comment: @HolgerNielsen - Office2010Win32API_PtrSafe.exe only contains documentation so that you can see what the declarations should be. So there is no "installation of the PtrSave elements". The Win32API is part of Windows. To use it you just need to include the correct declarations in your code.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up. In my case, sadly nothing happens with the clipboard.

Comment: @HolgerNielsen - it seems that the Office clipboard is independent of the Windows clipboard, so I've learned something today! The first method you quote is for Excel only, so that won't work in Word. The other two methods both clear the Windows clipboard, but not the Office clipboard.

Comment: Yes, it is the Office clipboard I wish to clear. I have just send a request to Microsoft's help desk at https://www.justanswer.com asking how to clear the Office desktop. They responded that they could give the answer, but wanted payment first. I think they shoud change the site name from "www.justanswer.com" to "www.payfirstforanswer.com" (appropriate smiley goes here).

Comment: @HolgerNielsen - are you certain that justanswer.com is Microsoft's help desk? AFAIK Microsoft uses their own site https://answers.microsoft.com which is free to use.

Comment: You are correct, so I went to answers.microsoft.com and asked them how to clear the clipboard using a macro. That was four days ago, but I have received no reaction. Perhaps they don't know either, perhaps it is just not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this above code snippet and it worked well until recent software updates that prevented me to clear the office clipboard without opening clipboard window. My solution it's very simple - add just this to the code:

```vb
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function AccessibleChildren Lib "oleacc" (ByVal paccContainer As Office.IAccessible, _
    ByVal iChildStart As Long, ByVal cChildren As Long, _
    ByRef rgvarChildren As Any, ByRef pcObtained As Long) As Long
    Public Const myVBA7 As Long = 1
#Else
    Private Declare Function AccessibleChildren Lib "oleacc" (ByVal paccContainer As Office.IAccessible, _
                                                              ByVal iChildStart As Long, ByVal cChildren As Long, _
                                                              ByRef rgvarChildren As Any, ByRef pcObtained As Long) As Long
    Public Const myVBA7 As Long = 0
#End If

Public Sub EvRClearOfficeClipBoard()
    Dim cmnB, IsVis As Boolean, j As Long, Arr As Variant
    Arr = Array(4, 7, 2, 0)                      '4 and 2 for 32 bit, 7 and 0 for 64 bit
    Set cmnB = Application.CommandBars("Office Clipboard")
   
'Just add here...First
'---------------------    
    With Application
       .DisplayClipboardWindow = True
    End With

    IsVis = cmnB.Visible 

    If Not IsVis Then
        cmnB.Visible = True
        DoEvents
    End If

    For j = 1 To Arr(0 + myVBA7)
        AccessibleChildren cmnB, Choose(j, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 1), 1, cmnB, 1
    Next
        
    cmnB.accDoDefaultAction CLng(Arr(2 + myVBA7))

    Application.CommandBars("Office Clipboard").Visible = IsVis

'And finish with this
'--------------------
    With Application
       .DisplayClipboardWindow = False
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: See my edit - please note the conventions for formatting [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

EvR's macro to clear the [Office Clipboard](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/copy-and-paste-using-the-office-clipboard-714a72af-1ad4-450f-8708-c2931e73ec8a) is very clever. (See [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64946949/10172433).) It works in Excel with my 64-bit Microsoft (Office) 365 and Windows 10.

VBA7 was introduced with Office 2010; everyone should have it by now. The vba7 directive does not distinguish 64-bit; the win64 directive does that, if it was needed. So here is my version of EvR's macro:

```
Declare PtrSafe Function AccessibleChildren Lib "oleacc" ( _
    ByVal paccContainer As Office.IAccessible, _
    ByVal iChildStart As Long, ByVal cChildren As Long, _
    ByRef rgvarChildren As Any, ByRef pcObtained As Long) As Long
Sub ClearOfficeClipboard()
    Dim A() As Variant, CB As Variant, n As Variant, i As Integer
    With Application
        If Not .DisplayClipboardWindow Then
            ClearClipboard
            .DisplayClipboardWindow = True
            ClearOfficeClipboard ' recurse
            Exit Sub
        End If
        On Error GoTo ErrHandler
        Set CB = .CommandBars("Office Clipboard")
        A = Array(0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 1)
        For i = 0 To UBound(A)
            AccessibleChildren CB, A(i), 1, CB, n
        Next i
        CB.accDoDefaultAction CLng(0)
    End With
ErrHandler:: Set CB = Nothing
End Sub
```

The ClearClipboard macro is from Chip Pearson, http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Clipboard.aspx. (See Timothy Rylatt [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64066682/10172433), but substitute vba7 in place of win64.)

I don't understand the For loop that calls AccessibleChildren. Can someone explain how it works? Note that CB must be Variant, not CommandBar or Object.