# Problems with Obj.Putinclipboard

Tags: excel, vba, windows, microsoft-file-explorer

I am having a problem with OBJ.PutInclipboard but only sometimes. the code below is what I am using

```
Dim OBJ as new DataObject
Dim txt as string

txt = "This goes in clipboard"
OBJ.settext txt
OBJ.Putinclipboard
```

this works well. But sometimes there is a glitch that will not allow me to put it in my clipboard if I have Windows file explorer open. I believe there may be a work around but am not sure how I would do it. is there any way to Fix this problem without a huge work around?
and if not is there any way to have VBA close all open file folders and save their location. For the user to then put the item in the clipboard and once complete run another VBA to open all saved locations that were closed back to where they were.

Comment: Whenever you are working with the clipboard is a good idea to clear it before, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32736915/how-to-clear-office-clipboard-with-vba) should address your problem, if it is further than that, try [this](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/clear-clipboard/) instead

Comment: You might find setting the clipboard via the Windows API more reliable: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/windows-api/send-information-to-the-clipboard

Comment: @ Tim Williams i tried this and it did not work it said variable not defined

Comment: @Tim williams on this line  DoCmd.RunCommand "acCmd"Copy  the quoted area is where it highlighted for the error. is there a library i may have to enable?

Comment: I was pointing to the Windows API part of that page - the first method is Access-specific, so it's not going to work in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

As others have indicated the issue occurs when Windows File Explorer is open before the Excel session, unless said explorer is currently as a system location eg. 'This PC' - go figure.

They have also suggested using Windows API, unfortunately MS have implemented its ASR (Attack Surface Reduction) of MS Defender shockingly poorly wrt. VBA, so that unless you frig it, (until they stop that), such WinApi call code can trigger Anti-Virus blocks.  The code below is another put-to-clipboard alternative for Excel:

```
Public Sub ClipboardPut(Optional ByVal vContent As Variant) ' , Optional ByVal vContentType As Variant = gconContentType) 
    Const conShapeName As String = "Clipboard_TempStage_Content"
    Dim oCtl
    
    On Error Resume Next
    ' just in case
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(conShapeName).Delete
    On Error GoTo ClipboardPut_err
    
    Set oCtl = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.TextBox.1", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False)
    With oCtl
        .Name = conShapeName
        .Visible = False
        With .Object
            .MultiLine = True
            .Text = vContent
            .SelStart = 0
            .SelLength = Len(.Text)
            .Copy
        End With
        .Delete
    End With

ClipboardPut_exit:
    Set oCtl = Nothing
    Exit Sub
ClipboardPut_err:
    With Err
        MsgBox "Error(" & .Number & ") - " & .Description, vbExclamation, "ClipboardPut", .HelpFile, .HelpContext
    End With
    Resume ClipboardPut_exit
End Sub
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

This may be a late answer, but I hope to help someone one day who has the same problem.
It seems to be a bug from Windows 8 and later. the function OBJ.Putinclipboar that you use can work properly if another windows folder or files (sometimes) is open.

i found this article on that site who can help : https://chandoo.org/forum/threads/clipboard-copy-vba-code-not-working-in-windows-10.37126/

Comment: @jmoerdyk I don't think this counts as link only. why do you think so?